# select2 with hierarchy JSON into option groups?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

For a given JSON structure like so:

```
    {
    "fruit": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Orange"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Apple"
        }
    ],
    "vegetables": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Potato"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Carrot"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Broccoli"
        }
    ]
}
```

When passing this into a select2 method as "data", how can I get this information to render as option groups like so?

```
<select>
<optgroup label="fruit">
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="vegetable">
    <option>Potato</option>
    <option>Carrot</option>
    <option>Broccoli</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution :

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single"></select>

<script>
var data = {
    "fruit": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Orange"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Apple"
        }
    ],
    "vegetables": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Potato"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Carrot"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Broccoli"
        }
    ]
};



   $().ready(function(){
var parsedJsonString = JSON.stringify(data); // get json string
var parsedJsonObject = $.parseJSON(parsedJsonString); // convert json string to object
$.each(parsedJsonObject,function(ele)
{
    $(".js-example-basic-single").append("<optgroup label='" + ele + "'>");
    $.each(parsedJsonObject[ele],function(subEle)
     {
         $(".js-example-basic-single").append("<option value='" + parsedJsonObject[ele][subEle]["id"] + "'>" + parsedJsonObject[ele][subEle]["name"] + "</option>");
    });   
    $(".js-example-basic-single").append("</optgroup>");
});


$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1ozynyu/3/